# Camel execution handling based on http response code

Tags: apache-camel

I am using http4 component and multicasting the msg to multiple routes. Each route is calling a Rest service. Based on http response code I want to handle the exception. I am getting httpOperationFailedException for all 400,500 response code but for 404 case I want to continue the routing and for other cases the execution should stop. How can I achieve this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Camel's error handling
http://camel.apache.org/error-handling-in-camel.html

There is a bit of documentation there to read and understand. But then you can do `onException` where you then have `onWhen` where you can then use the http status code to determine what to do, such as continue, or handle and return a specific error message etc.